# Удалить повторяющиеся элементы большого вектора на месте с сохранением порядка

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть большой массив std::vector неотсортированных значений, из которого необходимо удалить дубликаты (оставить только лишь единственное, первое вхождение) с сохранением порядка.

Задача решена с помощью дополнительного std::vector и std::set:

```
std::vector<int> result;
std::set<int> s;
for (auto e : vec) {
  if (s.find(e) == s.end()) {
    s.insert(e);
    result.push_back(e);
  }
}
```

Но, т.к. исходный массив очень большой, это приводит к неэкономному расходу памяти на время операции.

Каким образом можно сократить расход памяти (в идеале преобразовывать исходный std::vector на месте)?

Comment: Без доп памяти никак (за вменяемое время). Сортировка с номерами может помочь, но тут то индексов нету (добавить можно?). Я бы сет использовал, только чуть-чуть по другому

Comment: @pavel Скорость роли не играет, главное как можно меньше памяти израсходовать..

Comment: Ну дык за квадрат двойным циклом... Памяти 0 надо дополнительной.

Comment: @pavel ну это на крайний случай )) авось есть варианты

Comment: Какой порядок числа элементов в векторе (их размер не важен).

Comment: четвертый, но целевая платформа - mcu с памятью с гулькин нос

Comment: Пишите все ограничения на входные данные. Универсального с сохранением порядка без доп памяти не будет быстрее квадрата. Может внешнюю память использовать можно? Если числа меньше 100к где-то то решение есть.

Comment: С сколько обычно уникальных значений и дубликатов? Если много, то с двойным циклом будет вполне шустро и далеко от худшего случая.

Comment: Ну по крайней мере записывать в начало исходного вектора точно можно. Т.е. вектор `result` - лишний. Заводится итератор `int *p = &vec[0]` и потом '*p++ = e`. В конце ресайз вектора по размеру set.